# Fatal memory Error at the bottom of the page but not WSD. What this means?

Tags: 6

I occasionally get the following error showing at the bottom of some pages when I'm logged in as Admin. I have seen this error before when the server didn't have enough php memory. But then always the page was WSD.

However I don't get WSD with the php memory error message I'm getting now.
It's just showing at the bottom of the page and the page itself works as usual.
What is the difference between this one and the one we get on WSD?
Can I just ignore it?

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 175112192) (tried to allocate 7015932 bytes) in  /public_html/includes/database.inc on line 225
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the amount of memory available in your php.ini file (i think) - making more memory available to your drupal installation and thereby doing away with this error

see https://drupal.org/node/76156
and https://drupal.org/node/1915140

for further details

Comment: Thanks but probably my question was not clear. So I just revised it. I basically would like to know what is the difference between this error at the bottom of the page and the one we get with WSD.